# Insert external header with json

Tags: html, json

I would like to insert the external header using json. Since the page repeats many times in various pages I would like to do it externally. I tried to do it with javascript, but I didn't find a solution to my problem. Since I know it can be done with json, I wanted to ask, does anyone have any idea how I can do it?
I am creating a cinema site, where I have the header repeating on every page. I would like to insert the external header via json if there is a way. The header should be in a different folder than the index.

Comment: can you please provide more details? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, including an example of what you have tried and what isn't working as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I am creating a cinema site, where I have the header repeating on every page. I would like to insert the external header via json if there is a way. The header should be in a different folder than the index @Daniel A. White

Answer (score 1):

If you want change  use

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title id="header"></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    fetch('header.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = data.name;
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

if you want to change it to another place, change `id="header"` location

header.json:

```json
{
   "name": "Name"
}
```